# Error opening megawarc archive from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've found myself having to use a python script to access a webarchive.

What I have is a 'megawarc' web archive file from http://archive.org/details/archiveteam-fanfiction-warc-11.  I need to un-megawarc this, using the python script found at https://github.com/alard/megawarc.

I'm trying to run the 'restore' command, and I have the three files needed (FILE.warc.gz, 
FILE.tar, and FILE.json.gz) from the first link.

I have both python 2.7 and 3.3 installed.

--------------update--------------

I've ran both this method..

```
python megawarc restore FILE
```

and this method..

Make sure you have the files megawarc and ordereddict.py in the same directory, with the files you want to convert.
    Rename the file megawarc to megawarc.py
    Open a python console in this directory

```
Type the following code (line by line) :

import sys
sys.argv = ['megawarc','restore','FILE']
import megawarc
megawarc.main()
```

using python 2.7, and this is what I get..

```
c:\Python27>python megawarc restore FILE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "megawarc", line 563, in <module>
main()
  File "megawarc", line 552, in main
mwr.process()
  File "megawarc", line 460, in process
self.process_entry(entry, tar_out)
  File "megawarc", line 478, in process_entry
entry["target"]["offset"], entry["target"]["size"])
  File "megawarc", line 128, in copy_to_stream
raise Exception("End of file: %d bytes expected, but %d bytes read." % (buf_size, l))
Exception: End of file: 4096 bytes expected, but 236 bytes read.
```

Is there something else i'm missing?

I have the following files all in 
    c:\python27

```
FILE.megawarc.json.gz

FILE.megawarc.tar

FILE.megawarc.warc.gz

megawarc

ordereddict.py
```

Is this some type of corrupt file error?  Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: What did you try, what error did you get?

Comment: Pssh, nobody has the wrong mindset for programming. Simply the fact that you've been trying to solve a problem with programming means you could be a great programmer. It's all about problem solving.

Comment: So you executed the Python script you were given?  Did you open a command shell to run it so you could see the error messages, if any?

Comment: No need for self-deprecation: Think about Stack Overflow like a cookbook: the title and descriptions are the names of the recipes, the answers are the instructions for making the food.  A cookbook is a lot less valuable if the recipes are cluttered with side-comments.  Comments, in SO are like the side bars where you can share interesting tidbits, or apologize/explain yourself! :) Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 6):

On the second link you provided, there are two important files :

```
megawarc
ordereddict.py
```

The executable script is `megawarc`. To run it, you have to launch it in a shell with

```
python megawarc restore FILE
```

Alternatively, if you're using a UNIX-based system. You can do

```
chmod +x megawarc
```

To give megawarc script executable property and then run it with

```
./megawarc restore FILE
```

Here, `FILE` is the actual name you should type if the 3 files you have are `FILE.warc.gz`, `FILE.tar`, and `FILE.json.gz`. You have to change this parameter by the common prefix to your 3 input files if needed.

EDIT :

Okay, i found an alternative that would work if you don't have a standard shell to start the script in command line.
What you have to do is :

- Make sure you have the files `megawarc` and `ordereddict.py` in the same directory, with the files you want to convert.
- Rename the file `megawarc` to `megawarc.py`
- Open a python console in this directory
- Type the following code (line by line) :

  ```
  import sys
  sys.argv = ['megawarc','restore','FILE']
  import megawarc
  megawarc.main()
  ```

This should work, i've just tried it.
Hope it will help.

Comment: With the confusing caveat that FILENAME appears to be a filename prefix, not an actual filename.

Comment: >>> python megawarc restore test
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: megawarc is highlighted as being the invalid syntax

Comment: Oh, i see what's your problem. Actually, you're trying to start python as you are already in a python console. Do you have a shell ? (What's your OS ?)

Comment: using windows 7, have the python 3.3 shell IDLE (python GUI)

Comment: @SarahWaters - do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) and then open PowerShell, `cd` to your directory with your files, and do `python megawarc restore FILE` etc. etc. If your directory has spaces in it, enclose the directory in quotes, e.g. `cd "D:/My Python Scripts/"`

Comment: @SarahWaters more specifically, do [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753412/691859).